# Ruby. Cucumber, writing some steps with Xpath

Tags: ruby, cucumber, capybara

I have the following piece of HTMl.

```
<table id="movies">
 <thead><tr>
  <th><a href="/movies?ratings%5BPG%5D=1&amp;ratings%5BR%5D=1&amp;sort=title" id="title_header">Movie Title</a></th>
  <th>Rating</th>
  <th><a href="/movies?ratings%5BPG%5D=1&amp;ratings%5BR%5D=1&amp;sort=release_date" id="release_date_header">Release Date</a></th>
  <th>More Info</th>
 </tr></thead>
<tbody>
 <tr>
  <td>The Terminator</td>
  <td>R</td>
  <td>1984-10-26 00:00:00 UTC</td>
  <td><a href="/movies/2">More about The Terminator</a></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>When Harry Met Sally</td>
  <td>R</td>
  <td>1989-07-21 00:00:00 UTC</td>
  <td><a href="/movies/3">More about When Harry Met Sally</a></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Amelie</td>
  <td>R</td>
  <td>2001-04-25 00:00:00 UTC</td>
  <td><a href="/movies/6">More about Amelie</a></td>
 </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Now, i want to write the step in my Cucumber in order to check if the specified "ratings" (the second column) are on the page or not.

So, i wrote this (this is a part of the bigger code from my step defination but i checked, everything works till this place):

```
  txt = "//table[@id='movies']/tbody//td[2]"
  page.all(:xpath, txt) do |element|
    debugger
    puts element.text
  end
```

However, there seems to be somewhere a small error, because i never get inside this page.all block... no debugger is invoke, for instance.

Any Help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some meditative minutes the problem was fixed im my mind :)
I simply needed to give .each at the end.

```
txt = "//table[@id='movies']/tbody//td[2]"
 page.all(:xpath, txt).each do |element|
 debugger
 puts element.text
end
```

Comment: It's ok to answer your own question (and even accept your own answer as correct), but please pretend you're on a game show and actually leave the question as the question and put the answer here. I've edited your question and this answer to follow this pattern.